# How can i convert ARRAY into VARIABLE?

Tags: php, arrays

I need help in wishlist member plugin code. I need to get the level id of logged user.

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

   $my_user_id= $current_user->ID;

$mywlmapi= new WLMAPI();

$my_user_levels=$mywlmapi->GetUserLevels($my_user_id );
var_dump( $my_user_levels);

?>
```

Right now output is: `array(1) { [1458795207]=> string(16) "Bronze per month" }`

i need to store 1458795207 in `var $levelid = 1458795207`,

So i can `echo $levelid` and get the level id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $levelid = key($my_user_levels);

Comment: Thanks @splash58 its working for me.